# Sass (Ruby CSS compressor) absolute path parameters on Windows

Tags: css, windows, ruby, sass, absolute-path

I'm using `sass` (from [haml-edge](http://rubygems.org/gems/haml-edge)) for processing `css` files, and it crashes on absolute paths as parameters:

```
K:\sass>sass.bat k:/sass/css/*.scss k:/sass/css/*.css --trace
d:/Programs/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-edge-3.1.62/lib/sass/files.rb:23:in `read': No such file or directory - k
 (Errno::ENOENT)
    from d:/Programs/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-edge-3.1.62/lib/sass/files.rb:23:in `tree_for'
    from d:/Programs/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-edge-3.1.62/lib/sass/plugin.rb:220:in `update_stylesheet'
    from d:/Programs/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-edge-3.1.62/lib/sass/plugin.rb:71:in `block in update_stylesheets'
    from d:/Programs/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-edge-3.1.62/lib/sass/plugin.rb:71:in `each'
    from d:/Programs/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-edge-3.1.62/lib/sass/plugin.rb:71:in `update_stylesheets'
    from d:/Programs/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-edge-3.1.62/lib/haml/exec.rb:433:in `watch_or_update'
    from d:/Programs/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-edge-3.1.62/lib/haml/exec.rb:349:in `process_result'
    from d:/Programs/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-edge-3.1.62/lib/haml/exec.rb:41:in `parse'
    from d:/Programs/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-edge-3.1.62/lib/haml/exec.rb:21:in `parse!'
    from d:/Programs/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-edge-3.1.62/bin/sass:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from d:/Programs/Ruby/bin/sass:19:in `load'
    from d:/Programs/Ruby/bin/sass:19:in `<main>'
```

I was able to make it work by commenting one condition in `split_colon_path` (Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\haml-edge-3.1.62\lib\haml\exec.rb):

```
def split_colon_path(path)
  one, two = path.split(':', 2)
  if one && two && #### this part was commented #  ::Haml::Util.windows? &&
      one =~ /\A[A-Za-z]\Z/ && two =~ /\A[\/\\]/
    # If we're on Windows and we were passed a drive letter path,
    # don't split on that colon.
    one2, two = two.split(':', 2)
    one = one + ':' + one2
  end
  return one, two
end
```

Is there a better solution for platform detection?

Comment: `sass` vs `k:/ssas/` -- is the first element of your pathname a typo?

Comment: @sarnold: small typo while replacing actual paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. It's fixed in the latest stable version of Sass, unless you're using mingw Ruby, in which case it'll be fixed in the next stable version (to be released this weekend).

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved in `haml-edge 3.1.64`.

For the record, `mingw` was added to the `host_os` possible values in `{Ruby folder}\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\haml-edge-3.1.64\lib\haml\util.rb`:

```
# Whether or not this is running on Windows.
#
# @return [Boolean]
def windows?
  RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|windows|mingw/i
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It looks like you're the one who explained this bug on the public internet index :)